# How present pairs of inputs for binary classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have some data about a video game.

**Data:**

A match up has a matchId. Each match up includes two teams, and each team sizes varies. For instance, 3v3, 4v4, 5v5, ... Data simplified as follow:

```
matchId playerId teamId victory
100     200        14     1
100     201        14     1
100     212        14     1
100     220        14     1
100     202        15     0
100     206        15     0
100     214        15     0
100     217        15     0
```

**Task:**

I like to use a binary classifier in Scikit to predict the victory value (0/1) based on players' feature.

**Questions:**

1. I'm looking for a way to present feature that the classifier detect which two teams played against each other, because the result of a match up depends on the opponent team.
2. Later, I would like to see which players had more effect on the match up result, and which skills are more effective in victory. Can I use importance rates in [Gradient Boosting Classifier?](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using a *sparse-vector* of all `player_ids multiplied with 2` (2 teams), where the chosen ones are indicated with a nonzero value like 1.

If there are `N players 0, ..., N-1`, and the `team A consists of 1, 3, 5`, `team B consists of 0, 2, 4`, the input looks like the following:

```
x_sample_0 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...N-1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...]
              ...team A...                 ... team B...
```

This should be a quite *powerful representation* (in regards to the information represented) of the task with *two obvious drawbacks*:

- the vector-size will get large (linear in the size of players)

  - this does not matter if the classifier is able to work with sparse data-structures (scipy.sparse) as there are mostly zeros
- there is the problem of symmetry, as each pairing A vs. B can also be encoded as B vs. A

  - at the cost of doubling the input sample-size, i would highly recommend adding the symmetric pairing as extra sample (sample-size is doubled)

    - remember too flip the output (meaning: encode y as the win/loss from first teams perspective)!
  - maybe enforcing a lexicographic-ordering which will always output a well-defined order between two pairings (if players can't play themself) can be used as an alternative (i would try the above first)

**Edit:**

One more alternative:

- introduce one variable for each possible team (e.g. `f_0 = team of 0, 2, 4`) and use this representation which has a different vector-size depending on the statistics
- this kind of loses some information and would need much more data